# Only One Test Is In Results (Tests tab) When Running JMeter Tests on TFS

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, jmeter, azure-pipelines

We are trying to run JMeter Tests on TFS and are trying to setup our pipeline.
We are trying to run multiple .jmx files for this test and have results published.

The problem is that our test step iterates through the multiple tests we have in our repository but the results (Under TESTS TAB) only show ONE of the tests. We would like to see ALL tests which were run in the results.

Our steps "work" but with only one result. Is there something we're missing for the FOR LOOP or anything we're not doing correctly for the publishing of the report?

Here is a listing of our steps in TFS:

**Start of TFS Steps**
(Get the tests from the repository)

- **Download build artifacts**
- **Run Jmeter Tests Using a FOR LOOP (see below)**
  *Script:*
  `rmdir /s /q $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\reports del /f $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\results.jtl echo %JMETER_HOME% forfiles /p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\  /m *.jmx /c "cmd /c C:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter.bat -n -f -t "@file" -l results.jtl -e -o reports" python $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\jtl_junit_converter.py $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\results.jtl $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\JUnit_results.xml`
- **Publish Test Results**
- **Upload qa Results**
- **Email Reports**

**End of TFS Steps**

Thank you in advance for your help.

We would like to see ALL test results instead of only one test.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the following arguments:

- `-f` which removes the .jtl results file and [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) if they exist
- `-l result.jtl` which writes the results into a single file

so you only have results of the **last** test execution.

I think you should replace `-l result.jtl` with `-f "@file.jtl". The same for` reports`.

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Comment: Would my edited command line script look like this?

> rmdir /s /q $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\reports del /f
> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\results.jtl echo
> %JMETER_HOME% forfiles /p $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\ 
> /m *.jmx /c "cmd /c C:\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter.bat -n -f -t
> "@file" -f "@file.jtl" -f "@file.jtl" reports" python
> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\jtl_junit_converter.py
> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\results.jtl
> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\qa.zip\JUnit_results.xml

this did not work
ty.
@dmitri-t

Comment: Hello to anyone else out there. I tried the above suggestion and it does not work. Also did I make the proper corrections?